# How do I limit the rotation of the camera in an FPS

Tags: game-engine

I have mouselook for my game but the player can look all the way up and down.  I want the camera to be limited in rotation like a normal fps.  Please help!

Comment: Please add more information to your question (the mouselook script, etc.)

Comment: By this I mean the "up" and "Down" rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mouse move script](http://riyuzakisan.weebly.com/mousemove-script.html#toc) allows cutomization. In order to restrict up/down rotation you could add the properties as shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I make BGE tutorials on my channel, and I have this exact solution, scripts, and .blend file in the description. Just keep watching through the video, I believe I show you how 3 minutes through. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2BL9AxORec

Comment: Do link, but also provide an answer that will stand for itself.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Link only answers are discouraged here; if the link goes down, so does the answer.